# (AngularJS Directive) Change model value on input blur

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, model, onblur

I have a ng-model input element where I would like to enter just integer, positive numbers, but in case of empty input set model value to "1".

I have created a directive, but after input blur it does not change model value to "1":

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.item = { qty: 2 };
})
.directive('cartQty', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem) {
        scope.$watch('item.qty', function (newValue, oldValue) {
            var arr = String(newValue).split('');
            if (arr.length == 0) return;
            if (newValue == 0) scope.item.qty = 1;
            if (isNaN(newValue)) scope.item.qty = oldValue;
        });
        elem.on('blur', function () {
            var value = String(elem[0].value);
            if (value.length == 0) scope.item.qty = 1;
        });
    }
  };
});
```

Here is live JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/buh86w8n/2/

Is there anyone who could help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`elem.on('blur', function(){ // code..})` is out side angular scope.

To change scope value inside `elem.on blur` event you have to call `$apply()`.

Here is [working plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y58zmJlD6wzfvs9NqgW9?p=preview)

**elem.on blur event** :

```
elem.on('blur', function () {
    var value = String(elem[0].value);
    if (value.length == 0){
        scope.item.qty = 1;
        scope.$apply();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just `$watch` for that input, if its empty set it on 1.

So it starts with 2, if u delete it it will be set to 1, else set it on any number.

Here is your code edited:

http://jsfiddle.net/buh86w8n/4/

Comment: Thanks! I was trying this method, but in this case it is not possible to remove the "1" from the input by the keyboard - `scope.$apply();` is the best solution in this case.